# How to empty an UIPageViewController (Remove ViewControllers inside)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller

After setting up a PageViewController I'd like to remove the view controllers inside, leaving it empty.

How can I do this?

I've tried the `setViewControllers:direction:animated:completion:` method passing `nil` or an empty array in the viewControllers param but it crashes.

How can I do this?

Comment: do you want to remove all content of viewController?

Comment: Yes, I want all the child view controllers of the UIPageViewController to get released

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If calling `setViewControllers:direction:animated:completion:` with `nil` for the `viewControllers` parameter crashes, try setting the view controllers to an array with a single empty view controller.

```
[pageViewController setViewControllers:@[UIViewController.new] direction:direction animated:true completion:nil];
```

Comment: When you have a dynamic implementation (setting VCs), this solution gave me repeated VCs. So to fix, I did like below

(1)        pageViewController.dataSource = nil
(2)     implement your dynamic logic to set no of VCs  
(3)        pageViewController.dataSource = self

Your answer is correct, just sharing my experience which helps someone.

Answer (score -1):

```
-(UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you return `nil` when you don't want a next page, not when you want an empty page controller.